# ls command by default is showing one line per file? How to change it?

Tags: command-line, gnome-terminal, ls

[image: The screenshot]

When I call the ls command, I expect it to show all the files/directories in the current directory, attempting to fit as many as possible on each line. But, somehow it is showing one file per line. How to change that behavior?

Comment: what `ls` command options you have used exactly? or did you just run `ls`? For latter case are the filenames large?

Comment: `-C` is used to sort by columns

Comment: Anything you messed with that could be a hint? ;)

Comment: Is `ls` defined as alias? What does `alias ls` return ?

Comment: Please post the output of `~/.bash_aliases`

Comment: Could it be that there is one file with a very very long name in the directory, forcing all file names into one column? Maybe this file has a name ending in all spaces?

Comment: @Jos suggestion is the most common cause. Would you elaborate it into an answer?

Comment: @heemayl I just ran ls

Comment: @kos it gave no output

Comment: @jhilmer alias ls return this "alias ls='ls --color=auto'"

Comment: Please add the output of `ls` to your question..

Comment: Apologies. I meant the *content* of `~/.bash_aliases` (and since you are there also the content of `~/.bashrc`).

Comment: Also, what does `stty size` says?

Comment: 20 77 is the output of stty @kos

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you are not mixing lowercase L with 1?

`ls -l` (**l**i**s**t **l**ong) shows a long list of 1 file per line but with as many lines as the terminal shows.

If "ls" is the only command that does this you might have used the "1" (digit one) option somewhere. `[man ls][1]`:

> -1   Prints one entry per line of output.

---

Your command could be aliased to using a "1". Check if it is with ...

```
alias ls
```

And to remove that use

```
unalias ls
```

and check again. If so find the alias (probably `.bashrc`) and fix it.

Comment: My money is on either the `alias` thing or a function named `ls` being declared

Answer (score 1):

There could be a file with a very long name, consisting mainly of spaces, in the directory. This will force the file list into a single column. To test for the presence of such a file name, do this:

`find . -name *\ \ \ *`

This will find filenames with three or more consecutive spaces.

Comment: No,  it is not the case

Answer (score 0):

use the command

```
ls | tr "\n" " "
```

This will remove the new line and thus will list all files on the same line.

You can make an alias to this command and add it to your .bashrc so you can use the alias instead.

```
gedit .bashrc
```

add the following line:

```
alias lll=' ls | tr "\n" " " '
```

Save an close then source your .bashrc

```
source .bashrc
```

Now you can use this alias by running the `lll` alias command.